# Highlighter traces on a sheet of paper

Tags: reverse-puzzling

<sub>This is an entry for the [16<sup>th</sup> Fortnightly Challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5509/fortnightly-topic-challenge-16-reverse-puzzling).</sub>

---

My friend was solving a puzzle but took the puzzle with him. However, he was solving it with highlighters and they left traces on the paper below the puzzle.

Here is the paper:
[image: highlighters]

**What was the puzzle?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like a

> Word Search,

both from the patterns of the lines

> horizontal, vertical, and both diagonals

and from the fact that they were using a highlighter.

Comment: Can you clarify why would you use around five different kind of colors for such a task?

Comment: Perhaps he's just a colourful fellow.

Comment: That is a correct answer!

Comment: That was my first thought even though I circle my letters in pencil rather than anything else :P

Comment: There are several places where 3 words overlap, which explains why more than 1. If you're using one, you might as well use multiple, and 5 seems as reasonable a number as 3 to have on hand.

Comment: In elementary school, teachers would do their solution in highlighter and hold up your paper with theirs behind it up to the light. It made it easy to verify you had everything.